# IIS https requests are 4-5 times slower than http, lsass.exe is consuming 40% CPU

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis, https

We have an ASP.NET application running on IIS on Windows Server 2016, hosted on a D48s Azure virtual machine (48 cores).

Most of the time, the web app is processing requests from regular users at a pace of 200-300 requests per seconds.

But at times, the server receives high incoming traffic as webhooks from external sites – up to **1000-5000 requests per second**.

When this happens, the **CPU usage** get really **high**, and we noticed that the Local Security Authority Process (**lsass.exe**) is consuming most of the CPU at that time: it can take up to **40-50% of the total CPU usage** (the orange graph is lsass.exe CPU usage):

[image: lsass.exe high CPU usage]

Needless to say, the server becomes really busy, and other requests start to slow down.

By the way, each webhook request is very lightweight and adds a record to a table in SQL Server, for later processing.

We made a load test on our server, and found out that lsass becomes so active only when requests are made using **https**. However, if the very same requests are made using **http**, lsass.exe is not active at all.

The second discovery was that when using http the server was able to process **4-5 times more requests** under the same load, compared to https!

Here is a screenshot from Performance Monitor: the green line show Requests per seconds, and the brown line shows lsass.exe CPU usage. On the left is what happens when using http, and on the right – when using https:

[image: Performance Monitor: https vs. http]

So the bottom line is that:

1. https makes the requests **4-5 times slower**.
2. When using https, **lsass.exe** starts to eat a lot of **CPU resources**.

Questions are:

1. Why is **lsass.exe** so active during https requests?

I found an article on the web saying that lsass.exe was used by IIS 6.0 to cipher / decipher https traffic, but that starting from IIS 7.0 it is no longer used. However, our experiments indicate the contrary.

I don't understand how 4000-5000 requests per seconds having a body of 3-5 kilobytes can make the the CPU of a 48-core server so busy.

2. Maybe there are some **hidden SSL settings** in IIS that can make https more efficient?
3. We found info on **SSL offloading**: can this be done on **Azure**?

---

**Update**

We created a **new Azure VM** from scratch (a 32-core D32s), installed IIS and created a simple ASP.NET Web Forms app that has only 1 **"Hello World" aspx page** that does nothing (no SQL Server requests etc.)

With JMeter we created a load test to this page, and the **same pattern** appeared here:

**1) http**: the server was processing **20 000 requests per second**, and **lsass.exe** was **not active**.

**2) https**: the server was processing only **1000-1500 requests per seconds**, and **lsass.exe** was consuming **10% of total CPU**.

Here is the **Performance Minitor graph** (http on the left, https on the right):

[image: Performance Monitor: http vs https]

By the way, JMeter and the ASP.NET web app were run from the same VM, so network round-trips were minimal.

How can **https be 15-20 times slower** than **http** in this simple situation?

And what is the role of **lsass.exe** in this situation?

Comment: What kind of certificate is used?

Comment: A PositiveSSL, purchased on https://www.ssls.com/, with 2048-bit key.

Comment: This link may be helpful for your problem: [How to troubleshoot high Lsass.exe CPU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/troubleshoot-high-lsass.exe-cpu-utilization).

Comment: samwu, I read this link, but: 1) Our VM is not an Active Directory Domain Controller, 2) Performance Monitor on the VM lacks the Active Directory Data Collector Set mentioned in the article (probably because it is present on Active Directory Domain Controllers only).

Comment: @MikhailGlukhov any solution on this?

Comment: I had the exact same problem. What I just did to solve it without touching the ASP .NET application itself was to allocate a nginx container to perform SSL offloading for my application's IIS server. Hence, I switched IIS's binding from HTTPS to HTTP. Lsass CPU usage is 0%. I'm happy now.

Comment: We started using a Load Balancer that takes https requests and then forward them via http to our virtual machine: thus, all the SSL enconding / decoding operations moved to the Load Balancer. So now the VM does not do any SSL operations, and lsass usage is almost zero. So it turns out that Windows itself is very inefficient at SSL operations.